# Self-Hosted Integration Runtime Copy Activity Timeout

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I’m trying to implement a pipeline in ADF where I copy data from a Function App to an on-prem SQL Server. I have installed the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime to access the on-prem database and set my copy activity to use the self-hosted IR.

First I was a getting a firewall error, so I added a rule to allow the node where IR is installed to call the function app but now I am getting a timeout error.

Any ideas why the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the General parameters of the copy activity.  Try to Increase **Timeout** of your copy activity. By default it is 7 days.
Also, try to increase the **retry** count in the copy activity. The default is zero (no retry). Increasing the count and **retry interval** should allow it to attempt to regain connection.
[image]

Please refer this **Microsoft Documentation**: [Troubleshoot copy activity on Self-hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-copy-activity-on-self-hosted-ir)